# r remove rows from a data frame that contain a duplicate of either combination of 2 columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am trying to remove rows from a data frame that contain either combination of 2 columns. For example, the following code:

```
vct <- c("A", "B", "C")
a <- b <- vct
combo <- expand.grid(a,b) #generate all posible combinations
combo <- combo[!combo[,1] == combo[,2],] #removes rows with matching column
```

generates this data frame:

```
 Var1 Var2
2    B    A
3    C    A
4    A    B
6    C    B
7    A    C
8    B    C
```

How can I remove rows are duplicates of any combination of the 2 columns, so that i.e. #4 A B is removed because #2 B A is already present? The resulting data frame would look like this:

```
 Var1 Var2
2    B    A
3    C    A
4    C    B
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can `sort` by `row` using `apply` with `MARGIN=1`, transpose (`t`) the output, use `duplicated` to get the logical index of duplicate rows, negate (`!`) to get the rows that are not duplicated, and subset the dataset.

```
combo[!duplicated(t(apply(combo, 1, sort))),]
#   Var1 Var2
#2    B    A
#3    C    A
#6    C    B
```

Comment: that did the trick, thanks!

Comment: @trock2000 No problem.  Glad to help you.

Comment: @akrun, Thanks, a very good method. Can you do it using dplyr by any chances?

Comment: @Alex try `combo %>% filter(!duplicated(str_c(pmin(Var1, Var2), pmax(Var1, Var2) )))`

Comment: @akrun, it seems I got the same result. Thanks!. Can you explain what `str_c(pmin(Var1, Var2), pmax(Var1, Var2)` does

Comment: @Alex It is pasting the elementwise min and max together from each row and then do the duplicated on that.  `min`, `max` returns based on the alphanumeric order

Comment: @akrun, thanks for the help